# Error while implementing iterator on a struct with a mutable life time

Tags: rust, iterator, lifetime, ownership

i was trying to implement an iterator over a complex struct, and to do that i decided to use a support structure, which points to the original one. (to do that i had to use lifetimes). i wrote the code for the reference iterator and it works. but if i write the same code for a mutable reference it doesn't work, the weird thing is that the error seems to have to do with lifetimes, and not with ownership

here is the code for iterating over the reference, and it works:

```
struct Iter<'a>{
    vec: &'a i32// i32 is just an example, assume is a more complex strict
}
impl<'a> Iterator for Iter<'a>{
    type Item = &'a i32;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        Option::Some(self.vec)//assume this actually iterate over something, again... is just an example
    }
}
```

here is the same code, but with mutable reference and it doesn't compile:

```
struct IterMut<'a>{
    vec: &'a mut i32
}
impl<'a> Iterator for IterMut<'a>{
    type Item = &'a mut i32;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        Option::Some(self.vec)
    }
}
```

the error i get is the following:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:19:9
   |
16 | impl<'a> Iterator for IterMut<'a>{
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
17 |     type Item = &'a mut i32;
18 |     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
   |             - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
19 |         Option::Some(self.vec)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ associated function was supposed to return data with lifetime `'a` but it is returning data with lifetime `'1`
```

could someone tell me why it doesn't work, and why it does work in the first example? (even if the lifetimes are exactly the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is shared references are `Copy` while mutable ones are not.
For your simple example this would work.

```rust
struct IterMut<'a>{
    vec: Option<&'a mut i32>
}
impl<'a> Iterator for IterMut<'a>{
    type Item = &'a mut i32;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.vec.take()
    }
}
```

The gist is you can't hold on to the reference you're returning.

Comment: so you are saying this was indeed an ownership problem, and the error message was a little bit far off perhaps?

Comment: @Luca The error message is exactly correct. Your original implementation returned references that didn't live long enough.